# Tomcat server is running but its resources are not found

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jersey

I´ve created an maven project with the jersey archetype  and attached a tomcat server to it. My tomcat server is running, but when i try to access to a resource, it does not appear (Error 404:Not found, 
The required resource is not available.)

I already have tried to change the server path to use tomcat installation option. Also, i added a project facet with a dynamic project module.

web.xml

```
 <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.telusko.pablo</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

pom.xml

```
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
            <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
        </dependency>

        <!-- uncomment this to get JSON support
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-binding</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        -->
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.26-b03</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

I only expect to can access the resources and not get the error 404.

Comment: Your project is probably not being deployed. I see this a lot with Maven/Eclipse users. I don't really use Eclipse, so I don't know the solution. Do you know how you can check if the project is being deployed?

Comment: Show us the Tomcat log output.

Comment: How can i display the log output in a windows machine. I can't find the catalina.out